# How can I produce an automatic footer without implicitly having to define one in every new jsp page I create?

Tags: html, css, jsp

Moreover, is there a particular practice/way to have a cascading style sheet automatically call a footer div in every instance when `<body>` or `<html>` tags are present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a page decoration system.  There are several, like [jsp-decorator](http://code.google.com/p/jsp-decorator/).  There's also a pretty extensive discussion about JSP page decoration [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988585/servlet-page-decoration-do-people-use-tiles-sitemesh-or-something-else).

CSS applies style to page elements, it does not insert stuff into pages...

The [SiteMesh tutorial](http://www.sitemesh.org/overview.html) might help to understand what page decoration is about...

Comment: This footer will have dynamic content and must be present across every page within the site. Is this the way of creating a footer footer section without having to painfully going to every page and writing <div id=footer>blah blah data</div>

Comment: @captain that is exactly what a decorator system aims to solve, please read some of the links.

Answer (score 1):

Jsp templates can be used.

[JSP templates to encapsulate Webpage layout and encourage modular design](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2000/jw-0915-jspweb.html)